# Mongodb Backup of Database command is not working

Tags: database, mongodb, backup

I am running below command for Mongodb database backup but it is not working fine.I am running below command.

```
mongodump --db mydb --out /var/www/html/'date +"%m-%d-%y"'
```

this command is not working for me it throw an error

**2019-07-15T11:02:50.758+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:12**

Please let me know what is wrong in this command and what is correct way for backup of database?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please specify from where you are trying to do Mongodb database backup ? from any server or from terminal or mongodump ?

Answer (score 0):

The dump command you are using is absolutely fine (provided that you are connecting to localhost:27017 with no authentication). The problem is with 'date +"%m-%d-%y"' this part. You are using single quotes instead of backticks. Try :

```
mongodump --db mydb --out "/var/www/html/"`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`
```

Comment: ,actually I was trying from mongodb shell but when I have ran it from common ubuntu ,terminal its working fine.